# Vuex - why don't JS variables work as expected?

Tags: javascript

### Problem

JS variables don't work as expected in Vuex store.

Let's say we want to clear an array called `content`:

```
state: {
  content: [1, 2, 3]
}
```

We could do it either directly:

```
state.content = []
```

Or if it's referenced multiple times, we would put it in a variable first and then modify it, like this:

```
let content = state.content
content = []
```

But for some reason, the second method doesn't work. Why?

### Code

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/dke68gwz/

```js
state: {
  content: [1, 2, 3]
},
mutations: {
  clearContent(state) {
    // Method 1 - works
    state.content = []

    // Method 2 - doesn't work
    // let content = state.content
    // content = []
  }
}
```

Comment: I mean if you assigning value to a global variable there is small possibility to change something, and when assigning local `context = []` you can not change anything anyhow except this variable, no hidden magic, no side effects, and it's difficult to imagine more basic rule of javascript. Not javascript. I bet there is no language that could do such magic on assigning local variables. Why learn frameworks before learning language or programming? And that's the problem with each question here about JS framework

Comment: Yea, that's it, that's why those old grumpies in universities teaching assembler, how processor works, how to code in C, and you asking are you mad, I can take js, ruby or python and I can know nothing and make programs, easy and fast! Well, maybe so, maybe nowadays you can learn framework doc and go with it to work, why not.

Comment: > I have never cleared arrays with [] before
I know only one way to clear array in JS: array.length = 0
array = [] is not a "clearing", it's new array, but who cares, new array, old array, whatever, vue will handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not so much to do with Vue as it is the nature of JavaScript. Anything except primitives in JavaScript are pass-by-reference right, so `let content = state.content` creates a reference.

When you're doing the assignment `content = []` you're essentially killing the reference that `content` had to `state.content` and you're giving it a new value.

```js
const state = { content: [1, 2, 3] }
let content = state.content


// [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]
console.log(state.content, content)

// [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]
// still using the existing reference
content.push(4)
console.log(state.content, content)

// [1, 2, 3, 4], []
// reference is gone, new assignment
content = []
console.log(state.content, content)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are just assigning `[]` to the `content` variable in the second example. This does not effect `state.content`. If you did `content.splice(0)` that would, however, empty the `state.content` Array. Assignment is just that, assignment. The variable assigned a non-primitive value is the same as the non-primitive. This does not mean that overwriting the variable eliminates the non-primitive. It just reassigns the variable.

```js
const state = {
  content: [1, 2, 3]
}
const content = state.content;
content.splice(0);
console.log(content);
```

Comment: Yeah, that worked. Thank you, I cannot believe I though I was emptying the original data by setting the variable to `[]`

Answer (score 1):

I would say it is because you are are making a copy of only the property of the state obj. essentially you are copying only a property from the object that actually has the "change" event listener attached. In essence, you are orphaning the property from the object that would be tracking it's changes.

let me know if this helps!

Answer (score 1):

That's because the `content` variable is a new instance, and you use the a computed variable using the `state.content`. That is, the `state.content` remains the same but now you have a new variable `content`, empty.

if you want use this any way, you can use:

```
let content = state.content;
content = [];
state.content = content;
```